# Compiling C program in NetBeans 7

Tags: c, netbeans, compilation

I have a problem with netbeans 7 about debugging and running C program, the problem is that after I wrote the code as the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("done");
    "khaled";

    return 0;
}
```

in the output panel everything goes well but there's not any real output project (excutable file) no window appears.

I use gcc complier as the C compiler.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "khaled"?

Comment: Did you notice that the C console is wrapped inside a netbeans window? it runs on the same place where you see compilation error